# Initialize your class with constructor which takes std::map as a parameter with brace-enclosed initializer

Tags: c++, std

I have a simple class with constructor which takes `std::map`. I want to initialize the class with pair of braze-enclosed initializer list. Here's what I've tried:

```
//X.h
#include <map>

template <class key, class value>
class X{
public:
    X(const std::map<key, value>& map) : m_map{map} {}

private:
    typename std::map<key, value> m_map;
};
//main.C

int main() { 
    std::map<char, int> m = {{'a', 5}};
    X<char, int> x = m; //valid
    X<char, int> y = {{'a', 5}}; // error
}
```

But I get an error.  I guess I have to implement different constructor to be able to initialize with a initializer list but I don't know how.

Comment: Please do include the error message in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not, you are missing another pair of curly braces. This should work:

```
X<char, int> y = { { {'a', 5 } } };
                 ^ ^ ^~~~~~~~~
                 | | initializes map element
                 | initializes the map
                 initializes your object
```

Comment: While this solves the OP's problem, could you explain the why of it?

Comment: @NathanOliver, added.

Comment: Close but not correct.  The inner most braces is the element, the next one is the initializer list for the map, and the outermost is the map itself.  `X<char, int> y = {{{{'a', 5}}}}` actually uses copy construction since the outermost is the object.

Comment: @NathanOliver, and what if we remove the assignment?

Comment: In this case I'd use `X<char, int> y({{'a', 5}});` to make it a little clearer. Brace-o-Mania indeed :-)

Comment: @r3musn0x, Thank you very much!